# TransformListener x10 higher CPU load in rclpy than rclpp

Tags: ros, ros2, transforms, tf2-ros, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### System info

- Operating System:

  - Docker + Ubuntu 20.04, 10th gen i7
  - Docker + Ubuntu 20.04, jetson AGX Xavier
- ROS2 Version:

  - Foxy binaries

### Steps to reproduce issue

Make sure the system is publishing transforms to `/tf` at 30Hz. Run a simple node with a `TransformListener` in python and in C++.

#### Python

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from tf2_ros.buffer import Buffer
from tf2_ros.transform_listener import TransformListener

class MyNode(Node):
    def __init__(
        self,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__("navigation_god_node")
        self.buffer = Buffer()
        self.listener = TransformListener(
            buffer=self.buffer, node=self, spin_thread=False
        )
        self.listener.buffer = self.buffer
        self.tm_main = self.create_timer(
            timer_period_sec=0.5,
            callback=self.timer_callback,
        )

    def timer_callback(self):
        if  self.buffer.can_transform(
            "camera_color_optical_frame",
            "map",
            rclpy.time.Time(seconds=0, nanoseconds=0).to_msg(),
        ):
            self.get_logger().info("Can transform")

def main(args=None) -> None:
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = MyNode()
    rclpy.spin(node)
    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

#### C++

```
#include <string>
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/time.hpp"
#include <tf2_ros/buffer.h>
#include <tf2_ros/transform_listener.h>
#include "tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h"

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using namespace std;

class MyNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
  public:
    MyNode(const string& node_name, const string& nm)
    : Node(node_name, nm)
    {
      _buffer_tf2 = std::make_unique<tf2_ros::Buffer>(this->get_clock());
      _listener_tf2 = std::make_shared<tf2_ros::TransformListener>(*_buffer_tf2);
      timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(
      500ms, std::bind(&TFListenerNode::timer_callback, this));
    }

  private:
    void timer_callback()
    {
      if (_buffer_tf2->canTransform("camera_color_optical_frame", "map", tf2::TimePointZero))
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Can transform");
    }
    rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
    std::unique_ptr<tf2_ros::Buffer> _buffer_tf2;
    std::shared_ptr<tf2_ros::TransformListener> _listener_tf2;
};
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    auto tf_transforms_node = make_shared<MyNode>("listener_transforms_node", "tf_transforms");
    rclcpp::spin(tf_transforms_node);
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

### Expected behavior

Roughly the CPU load should be the same, at least not that big difference.

### Actual behavior

The python implementation loads the CPU almost 10x. Tested in my beefy laptop and in a Jetson.

#### My laptop

Python node: ~8% CPU one core
C++ node: ~1% CPU one core

#### Jetson

Python node: ~20% CPU one core
C++ node: ~2% CPU one core

In this case, it makes the python API unusable in a constraint environment like a Jetson.

Does anyone know any known issue with tf2_ros in python? Does this implementation look bad?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381395/transformlistener-x10-higher-cpu-load-in-rclpy-than-rclpp/) by [charlie92](https://answers.ros.org/users/64524/charlie92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2021-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not benchmarked this with rclpy but we saw the same behavior with rospy and roscpp where actually just subscribing to the `/tf` topic in python takes that order of magnitude CPU to receive the firehose of high frequency data.

To that end we created the tf2 buffer_server.  It providea an action based API for querying transforms from another node. You can find some pointers in the tf2 MIgration notes:  http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Migration

The c++ implementation of the Listener be default provides this API. And you can just create the buffer_client and point it at an existing buffer_server running on a neighboring c++ node.

The ROS 2 implementation parallels the ROS 1 implementation.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2021-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [charlie92](https://answers.ros.org/users/64524/charlie92/) on 2021-06-29**:
Thank your for the information, I didn't know about this server and actually I was thinking on implementing a kind of buffer_server. I suppose we can just use this client in python https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/ros2/tf2_ros_py/tf2_ros/buffer_client.py